# ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-43): Failed getting banner

Tags: php, libssh2, ssh2-sftp, ssh2

Have a docker container build using php-ssh2. php version 7.2 When trying to use

```
$con = ssh2_connect('hostname');
```

I am getting `Error starting up SSH connection(-43): Failed getting banner` . Interesting thing is `43` here. Whats the significance of `43`. What does that mean? Also any idea how to fix this? There is no heavy load, running connection manually.

Answer (score 3):

#### Deepdive into `libssh2`

This number `-43` is an error code that comes directly from `libssh2`, specifically [`LIBSSH2_ERROR_SOCKET_RECV`](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/f553dcc95ddd9683ac572dd8aa66ba877f6be39d/include/libssh2.h#L502). The [`Failed getting banner`](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/cfe0bf64985fd6a5db3b45ffc31a2fe3b8fd9948/src/session.c#L731-L732) message is the dynamic error message that accompanies the error code. These two pieces of information give the location where this error is thrown, namely in the [`receive_banner`](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/cfe0bf64985fd6a5db3b45ffc31a2fe3b8fd9948/src/session.c#L88-L186).

#### Underlying problem

It was the result of the socket throwing a receive error when `libssh2` tried to read from it as part of initialising your SSH session. Either the server is misconfigured and is not sending a banner or the underlying connection disconnected for some reason.

#### Solution

The best course of action seems to have adequate retrying in place for these kinds of errors. You are connecting to a network which is an action that can fail. As the number of servers you are connecting to increases, you are going to run into errors that are a result of the underlying network. Adequate error handling is your best course of action.

You can find how to set exception handlers from the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).